# LM7171 - Follower

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to isolate part of my circuit with a voltage follower (LM7171). The signal at the op amp non-inverting input is PWM (12 V, 0 V) with a frequency of 20 kHz. It is attenuated by the voltage divider (6 V, 0 V) when the op amp is not connected.

When the op amp is connected to (+12 V, 0 V), the PWM at the non-inverting pin shifts from (6 V, 0.9 V). What's causing this offset in the PWM?

I thought it was caused by the grounds but I have disregarded it already by connecting all the grounds as close as possible.

[image]

Comment: (inspection of the datasheet tells you that the input and output voltage ranges of the LM7171 do not reach the negative supply voltage. So, this is very expected and documented!)

Comment: LM7171 : Specified for ±15V and ±5V Operation

Comment: Why use an opamp to process PWM signal? You will get terrible accuracy near 0% and 100% due to slew rate.